# Socket.io emitting [object Object] with mongoDB document

Tags: javascript, mongodb, socket.io

First of all, Happy Thanksgiving to everyone! I hope everyone enjoys all the food they'll be eating! I know I will..

Any who,

I'm trying to query my mongoDB collection for the most recent document that has been inserted and emit it to the client. However, the only thing that is showing up on the webpage is [object Object] instead of the data stored in the document. When I console.log the data being sent it shows this:

```
Object {newData: Array[1]}
newData: Array[1]
0: Object_id: "564f8b8cfa74e4daab1543ca"
ambientAtTrackTempSensor: "-"
date: "10/09/2015"
dewPoint: "56"
humidity: "63.0"
pressure: "29.258"
solar: "397"
temp: "80.1"
time: "17:00"
trackTemp: "-"
windBearing: "222"
windGust: "7.0"
windSpeed: "6.0"
__proto__: Object
length: 1
__proto__: Array[0]
__proto__: Object
```

So the data is there, I assume I'm just not accessing it correctly.

Here is my code:

Server:

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

MongoClient.connect(dbUrl, function(err, db) {
  if (err) {
    console.log('Failed to connect to mongoDB database.');
  } else {
    console.log('Succesfully connected to mongoDB database.');
  };

io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
// send data to client
  var collection = db.collection('track_weather');
  collection.find().sort({_id:-1}).limit(1).toArray(function(err, docs) {
    console.log(docs);
    socket.emit('message', {'newData': docs});
  });
 });
});
```

Client:

```
<body>

<script>
  var socket = io.connect();

  socket.on('message', function(data) {
    $('#newData').text(data.newData);
    console.log(data);
  });
</script>

<div id="newData"></div>

</body>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! I'm very new to all of this :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must stringify your object to display it or javascript will just display the type (`[object Object]` here).

```
$('#newData').text(JSON.stringify(data.newData));
```

Comment: No problem, it's a common mistake and I made it few times too :)